# From Doctrine Query to QueryBuilder in a Simfony2 entity field type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I'm using the *entity Field Type* in a *Symfony2.1* form. Here, I'm going to use the `query_builder` param to return only entities that matches a long-complex query (see the example in the [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)).

Obviously the `query_builder` param for the entity field type accepts a Doctrine *QueryBuilder* object. On the other side, I have large entity repositories with complex DQL queries obtained by the *EntityManager*'s `createQuery()` function which returns a Doctrine *Query* object. 
So, I cannot directly use all these queries in the entity field type. Moreover, rewriting all the queries for the use with a QueryBuilder would be a non-sense.

Is there such a way to automatically translate from the *Query* object to the *QueryBuilder* object?

Comment: Alternatively you can use `choice_list` option of the choice form type. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257787/how-to-use-choicelist-in-symfony-2-1/) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Symfony2 docs:

> **query_builder** - type: `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder` or a `Closure` <---
>
> If specified, this is used to query the subset of options (and their
>   order) that should be used for the field. The value of this option can
>   either be a `QueryBuilder` object or a `Closure`. If using a `Closure`, it
>   should take a single argument, which is the `EntityRepository` of the
>   entity.

Now, I haven't got time to try an example but it seems to me that if you use `Closure` you could return `ArrayCollection` (or at least `array`) of target entity objects. Your `Closure` gets object of `EntityRepository` as an argument so there's no need to rewrite all that stuff.

Mind giving it a shot? :)

## UPDATE

... sorry for kept you waiting...

It seems that it's not possible this way. Instead you would have to use `choice` form type and feed entity objects (or objects repository as I did) manually.

I've made some simplified example here: http://ideone.com/LHdi2E

Hope this helps...

Comment: Well, I've seen that in the docs too. However, I didn't find any example on the Web. Would you integrate your answer with a small example of a closure that uses Query object instead of the QueryBuilder? Of course, you can take your time...

Comment: Sure thing! But first I would need to return home from work (in next few hours) ;)

Comment: Hey @JeanValjean, I have updated my answer... please check it out :)